# Men reincarnated as women -- a movie

Tags: story-identification

There was a movie where two misogynists died but were given a second change to come back to Earth and live their lives over as women; on the condition that they couldn't return to heaven (i.e, wouldn't be allowed in) unless they were 'redeemed by the love of another woman'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is [Switch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103016/) from 1991.

The main protagonist fits your description but there was only one of him.

> A sexist, chauvinist pig gets his just desserts when his angry
>   ex-girlfriends murder him and he is reincarnated as a woman.

[image]

Comment: I think so, thanks!